# HTML5 geolocation in facebook app browser - no allow/block prompt

Tags: android, html, facebook, browser, geolocation

I have a website which uses HTML5 geolocation. It works very well except through the Android Facebook in-app browser. This is the internal app browser that opens when a link is clicked in the Facebook app.

Normally when accessing the page a user would get a use location prompt (Allow / Block) but in the Facebook app nothing is requested and the page/site doesn't have location access.

Does anybody, for the love of all that's holy, know a solution to this or even a way around it?

I'm kind of at my wit's end here as I do not have a valid solution other than recognising that the user is in the Facebook browser and asking them to break out via the 'Open in Chrome' menu setting.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that the Facebook in-app browser doesn't implement the HTML5 geolocation API on purpose because that would be a very easy way for somebody to phish out people's location since a lot of people already allow location for their Facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

With geolocation i don't think you can avoid the prompt of 'allow/block'. That would cause security risks.

Back-end should return you the IP address. Check [How to get ip address using javascript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953328/how-to-get-ip-address-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: SOLVED

I know this is an old post, but I would like a fallback when a user visits a site that uses geolocation on the facebook app.

I have the folowing check, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
if ('geolocation' in navigator){
    //HANDLE GEOLOCATION
} else {
    detour();
}
```

Is there another check I can use the add a special case for facebook visitors?

UPDATE:
Just use:

```
if (navigator.gelocation) {...}
```