# How to get client public ip address in servlet java

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I am using Tomcat server with Java web application. 
I need client public IP address from request. But i am unable to get that, i used request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for") 
request.getRemoteAddr() methods but I get client machine Local IP address.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163874/get-real-client-ip-in-a-servlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running your server in a local network. If its in the wild `request.getRemoteAddr()`should do its job.

If you really need even in a local network your public IP which could all be the same in your local network since its behind a router or something that uses [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) it dosen't make much sense in my eyes. Even though if you want to get your public IP use a service like ipecho: http://ipecho.net/plain

Comment: If it is in local network then its not possible to get public ip ?

Comment: Thanks Zarathustra. I need it so I will try this service. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building web application in JSP & wants to send client's public IP address to the server, you can use JavaScript with JSP to achieve this.

```
//JavaScript dynamically created to obtain CLIENT MACHINE'S IP ADDRESS
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://www.telize.com/jsonip?callback=DisplayIP";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

        //below given function returns CLIENT MACHINE'S IP ADDRESS to the text box
        function DisplayIP(response)
        {
            document.getElementById("clientip").value = response.ip;
        }
```

IP address will be stored in clientip & pass it to the server list you post a form & pass it to a servlet.

Comment: Thanks The Joker for your attention. Thanks.